# Is there a known bug report for Selenium doing SendKeys() to the wrong input box?

Tags: c#, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Problem:**

I ran into what appears to be a bug in Selenium itself where it is doing a SendKeys() to the previous element I sent keys to, rather than a new one.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="w2ui-label">
    Provider Name
</div>
<div class="w2ui-field w2ui-required">
    <input id="ProviderName" type="text" style="width: 225px;" maxlength="100" name="ProviderName"></input>
</div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 250px;">
                <div class="w2ui-label">
                    User Name
                </div>
                <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-required">
                    <input id="UserName" type="text" style="width: 225px;" maxlength="100" name="UserName"></input>
                </div>
```

**C# code:**

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ProviderName")]
public IWebElement ProviderNameInput { get; set; }

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "UserName")]
public IWebElement UserNameInput { get; set; }

ProviderNameInput.SendKeys(providerName + Keys.Tab);
UserNameInput.SendKeys(username + Keys.Tab);
```

**AJAX:**

I'm told there is an AJAX request that fires off for the User Name field to validate the username, but there no similar request for the Provider Name field, so I'm not sure why Selenium would get hung up on that field. I tried sprinkling in AJAX waiters (wait for all jQuery requests to complete before moving on) without success.

**Environment:**

- .NET version of Selenium, version 2.35.0
- Firefox 24.0
- NUnit test runner
- Windows 7 SP1 64-bit

Comment: looks like we just ran into a similar issue. Have you had any luck resolving than problem?

Comment: we too ran into this issue